# Missing Date values in time series modeling using `R`

Tags: r, time-series, finance

I'm trying to get an intuitive idea of the use of time series in financial markets by attempting to reproduce [this post](http://programming-r-pro-bro.blogspot.com/2013/04/forecasting-stock-returns-using-arima.html). Since the dataset used in the blog is not accessible, I have used instead the `GOOG` ticker and the `quantmod` and `tseries` libraries:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)

getSymbols("GOOG")
str(GOOG) # We start with an xts
```

The series is not stationary calling for differencing:

```
GOOG_stationary = 100 * diff(log(GOOG$GOOG.Adjusted)) # Made stationary
```

Now when I try to run a time series model as called for in the blog, I get an error message as follows:

```
GOOG_stationary = 100 * diff(log(GOOG$GOOG.Adjusted)) # Made stationary
summary(arma(GOOG_stationary, order = c(2,2)))
Error in summary(arma(GOOG_stationary, order = c(2, 2))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': 
Error in arma(GOOG_stationary, order = c(2, 2)) : NAs in x
```

It seems as though there are `NA` values in the dates, but I don't know if these are weekends, or other gaps. There are no `NA` values in the actual prices: `sum(is.na(GOOG$GOOG.Adjusted))  [1] 0`, or in the dates: `sum(is.na(index(GOOG)))   [1] 0`.

It is likely to be a problem with **weekends and holidays**. If this is the case, how can it be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exclude the `NAs`. In this case just the first.

```
GOOG_stationary = 100 * diff(log(GOOG$GOOG.Adjusted))[-1]

summary(arma(GOOG_stationary, order = c(2,2)))

Call:
arma(x = GOOG_stationary, order = c(2, 2))

Model:
ARMA(2,2)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-12.41416  -0.86057  -0.02153   0.91053  18.17041 

Coefficient(s):
           Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)  
ar1        -0.19963          NA       NA       NA  
ar2         0.04969     0.65183    0.076   0.9392  
ma1         0.18210          NA       NA       NA  
ma2        -0.06049     0.66539   -0.091   0.9276  
intercept   0.05303     0.02783    1.905   0.0567 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Fit:
sigma^2 estimated as 3.62,  Conditional Sum-of-Squares = 8685.37,  AIC = 9916.97
```